# how can find continent along with country any free services in android

Tags: android, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

i am working on geocoder find country and city its working fine 
          already i am getting country name dynamically using geocoder 
       is their any chance to get in continent name along with country.
        it is difficult to maintain statically i need dynamically,any third party 
      free services u can find continent

Comment: @narashimha: "it is difficult to maintain statically" -- no, it is trivial to maintain statically.

Comment: yes it is difficult any third party free sites

Comment: down voted, cause created duplicate question of own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476876/how-to-find-continent-in-particular-location-using-geocoder-in-android-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create map of country continent in json using the list of countries available on internet.
One list I found was here.

http://www.worldatlas.com/cntycont.htm

Following question looks like a duplicate, with an answer **accepted**

[GeoLocation API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283158/geolocation-api)

Comment: downvote without a comment :( , so I searched more on internet for better answer and found this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283158/geolocation-api

Comment: this url i see this ,code statically in php not using in android its difficult i need dynamically find continent

Comment: Don't have idea about android, but idea remains the same, you can create the map of countries vs continent easily as there are 200 odd countries and 5 to 7 continents.....

Comment: If u haven't read completely... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283158/geolocation-api#answer-1283169

Comment: do u think, creating duplicate question of your own question helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476876/how-to-find-continent-in-particular-location-using-geocoder-in-android-app