# Latitude and Longitude range of land on earth

Tags: latitude-longitude

I'm writing a program where I need the range of latitudes and longitudes that correspond to land on the earth. This can be a rough approximation, but I'm not sure how to go about obtaining this range. I mainly want to differentiate the continents from the oceans.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905646/get-the-continent-given-the-latitude-and-longitude seems to give you a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [The Google Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/overview)

When you enter a coordiante which is ouside land (i.e. on a ocean) then the returned time zone is `ZERO_RESULTS`. This response you can use.