# Is there a way in R to tell what continent a certain lat/long coordinate belongs to?

Tags: r

I am using the `maps` package in R and want to make a text label over every continent that says how many of the points I am plotting are on each continent. Although I could make rough boxes that outline each continent, they are not that accurate and, for example, sometimes include parts of Europe in Africa and such.

Is there some functionality in R that will allow me to be able to tell, based on latitude/longitude coordinates, what continent a certain point belongs to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function to do it. I looked at [Get the continent given the latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905646/get-the-continent-given-the-latitude-and-longitude) and [GeoLocation API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283158/geolocation-api/1283168#1283168) for inspiration. Seems to work pretty well. Can't guarantee it won't break

```
continentFromLatLon <- function(lat, lon)
    {

        require(XML)
        require(RJSONIO)

        uri <- sprintf("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%s,%s&sensor=true", lat, lon)
        doc <- htmlParse(uri)

        root <- xmlRoot(doc)

        dat <- unlist(fromJSON(xmlValue(root[["body"]][["p"]][["text"]])))

        country <- dat[tail(grep("short", names(dat)), 1)]

        continents <- fromJSON('{"AD":"Europe","AE":"Asia","AF":"Asia","AG":"North America","AI":"North America","AL":"Europe","AM":"Asia","AN":"North America","AO":"Africa","AQ":"Antarctica","AR":"South America","AS":"Australia","AT":"Europe","AU":"Australia","AW":"North America","AZ":"Asia","BA":"Europe","BB":"North America","BD":"Asia","BE":"Europe","BF":"Africa","BG":"Europe","BH":"Asia","BI":"Africa","BJ":"Africa","BM":"North America","BN":"Asia","BO":"South America","BR":"South America","BS":"North America","BT":"Asia","BW":"Africa","BY":"Europe","BZ":"North America","CA":"North America","CC":"Asia","CD":"Africa","CF":"Africa","CG":"Africa","CH":"Europe","CI":"Africa","CK":"Australia","CL":"South America","CM":"Africa","CN":"Asia","CO":"South America","CR":"North America","CU":"North America","CV":"Africa","CX":"Asia","CY":"Asia","CZ":"Europe","DE":"Europe","DJ":"Africa","DK":"Europe","DM":"North America","DO":"North America","DZ":"Africa","EC":"South America","EE":"Europe","EG":"Africa","EH":"Africa","ER":"Africa","ES":"Europe","ET":"Africa","FI":"Europe","FJ":"Australia","FK":"South America","FM":"Australia","FO":"Europe","FR":"Europe","GA":"Africa","GB":"Europe","GD":"North America","GE":"Asia","GF":"South America","GG":"Europe","GH":"Africa","GI":"Europe","GL":"North America","GM":"Africa","GN":"Africa","GP":"North America","GQ":"Africa","GR":"Europe","GS":"Antarctica","GT":"North America","GU":"Australia","GW":"Africa","GY":"South America","HK":"Asia","HN":"North America","HR":"Europe","HT":"North America","HU":"Europe","ID":"Asia","IE":"Europe","IL":"Asia","IM":"Europe","IN":"Asia","IO":"Asia","IQ":"Asia","IR":"Asia","IS":"Europe","IT":"Europe","JE":"Europe","JM":"North America","JO":"Asia","JP":"Asia","KE":"Africa","KG":"Asia","KH":"Asia","KI":"Australia","KM":"Africa","KN":"North America","KP":"Asia","KR":"Asia","KW":"Asia","KY":"North America","KZ":"Asia","LA":"Asia","LB":"Asia","LC":"North America","LI":"Europe","LK":"Asia","LR":"Africa","LS":"Africa","LT":"Europe","LU":"Europe","LV":"Europe","LY":"Africa","MA":"Africa","MC":"Europe","MD":"Europe","ME":"Europe","MG":"Africa","MH":"Australia","MK":"Europe","ML":"Africa","MM":"Asia","MN":"Asia","MO":"Asia","MP":"Australia","MQ":"North America","MR":"Africa","MS":"North America","MT":"Europe","MU":"Africa","MV":"Asia","MW":"Africa","MX":"North America","MY":"Asia","MZ":"Africa","NA":"Africa","NC":"Australia","NE":"Africa","NF":"Australia","NG":"Africa","NI":"North America","NL":"Europe","NO":"Europe","NP":"Asia","NR":"Australia","NU":"Australia","NZ":"Australia","OM":"Asia","PA":"North America","PE":"South America","PF":"Australia","PG":"Australia","PH":"Asia","PK":"Asia","PL":"Europe","PM":"North America","PN":"Australia","PR":"North America","PS":"Asia","PT":"Europe","PW":"Australia","PY":"South America","QA":"Asia","RE":"Africa","RO":"Europe","RS":"Europe","RU":"Europe","RW":"Africa","SA":"Asia","SB":"Australia","SC":"Africa","SD":"Africa","SE":"Europe","SG":"Asia","SH":"Africa","SI":"Europe","SJ":"Europe","SK":"Europe","SL":"Africa","SM":"Europe","SN":"Africa","SO":"Africa","SR":"South America","ST":"Africa","SV":"North America","SY":"Asia","SZ":"Africa","TC":"North America","TD":"Africa","TF":"Antarctica","TG":"Africa","TH":"Asia","TJ":"Asia","TK":"Australia","TM":"Asia","TN":"Africa","TO":"Australia","TR":"Asia","TT":"North America","TV":"Australia","TW":"Asia","TZ":"Africa","UA":"Europe","UG":"Africa","US":"North America","UY":"South America","UZ":"Asia","VC":"North America","VE":"South America","VG":"North America","VI":"North America","VN":"Asia","VU":"Australia","WF":"Australia","WS":"Australia","YE":"Asia","YT":"Africa","ZA":"Africa","ZM":"Africa","ZW":"Africa"}')

        continents[country]

     }
```

Sample output:

```
R> continentFromLatLon(35, -98)
              US
 "North America"
R> continentFromLatLon(51, 0)
       GB
 "Europe"
```

Comment: Nice, but assumes that countries do not cross continents. Istanbul and Wladivostok will be wrong.