# AngularJs autocomplete and continents

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps

I'm using autocomplete with angularjs (http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAutocomplete). I want to return a continent of selected city, but how can I do this?
I get the next request (for ex. with response "Alabama, NY, United States"):

```
address_components: Array[6]
adr_address: "Alabama, NY 14013, USA"formatted_address: "Alabama, NY 14013, USA"geometry: vicinity: "Alabama"
```

In the address_components array there is not any point with continent:
address_components:

```
Array[6]
0: 
long_name: "Alabama"
short_name: "Alabama"types: 
Array[2]0: "locality"
1: 
long_name: "Alabama"
short_name: "Alabama"
types: Array[2]0: "administrative_area_level_3"
2: 
long_name: "Genesee County"
short_name: "Genesee County"
types: Array[2]0: "administrative_area_level_2"
3: 
long_name: "New York"
short_name: "NY"
types: Array[2]0: "administrative_area_level_1"
4: 
long_name: "United States"
short_name: "US"
types: Array[2]0: "country"
5: 
long_name: "14013"
short_name: "14013"
types: Array[1]0: "postal_code"
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it exactly with using autocomplete with AngularJS, but the basic ideas are doing polygon analysis with your coordinates. Here's an [**example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183873/google-maps-api-get-continent-where-the-country-is-located)